# how does the skipper-client help app get their streamDeploymentProperties?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

wanna know how skipper help the application installed by it get their properties?

for example, i depoly a stream in scdf by using http | log and i've config http with server.port=8088, how does it get this property?

Answer (score 0):

SCDF sends the StreamDeployment properties as specific **app** deployment properties set for each app that gets deployed for the Stream.

At the Skipper side, the app deployment properties are set in the [Spec](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-skipper/blob/4fa0a5f98b623f61f7220fc2277a7e70d4e07c16/spring-cloud-skipper/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/skipper/domain/SpringCloudDeployerApplicationSpec.java#L42) of the application getting deployed.

Comment: tks, and could you plz tell which method skipper uses to inject these properties.